# Localized content within same localization

Tags: localization

In the project I am working has got new requirements !!

They want us to include additional language without creating more publications (as we already have 2 more besides English) and that for specific CTs and PTs. I was thinking to use a language parameter from which I can get a set of specific pages/components with that language parameter defined.

Am i going right way..of course it will be a whole new level of customization for... but has this been done before.. I mean like creating all localized content in the same publication.

Any answers much appreciated.

Comment: When you state "localizations" are you referring to Publications or the published website(s)?

Comment: Yup.. Publications

Comment: It seems to me you're working against the real differentiator in the CMS here (specifically for translation/localization). I'd be more interested in understanding the case for *not* using blueprinting. Otherwise, I guess you're just going to create /content/language_x/ content folders - (and SG). At this point you'll be managing more content with no link to assess - what's been translated/localized etc. and the OOTB translation tools will not likely play nice with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mark and Rick on this one.

I’ve seen many similar projects that start with “Let’s put them in the same Publication - It’s only a few pages”, and end up becoming a major unpicking job later down the line after the scope expands.

As well as working against how translations (and Translation Manager) should work within the CMS, you’ll also be introducing possible future limitations (or unnecessary complexity) around things such as:

- Content reuse
- Tridion Security (Rights, permissions, etc.)
- Workflow and Minimal Approval Statuses
- Publishing and Environments

Unless you have license restrictions that you can’t get around, then I’d recommend going with using additional Publications. You could always create and use new ‘Publication Type’ values for these, if you wanted to allow editors to filter them out from the list of Publications in the CME interface.

Answer (score 1):

Not using BluePrinting for languages is definitely not going the right way.

For example, you won’t be able to use Translation Manager to do translation.